# Umbraco - editing preview window sidebar options

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a project which is using Umbraco v7.7.9 installed with nuget.

I was wondering if it is possible to change the buttons displayed in the sidebar section when a user selects to preview a content node. Particularly I want to remove the option that allows the user to close the preview.

The reason I want to hide this option is because some of the content the backoffice users will be previewing will not actually be published yet so clicking the close preview button causes an error.

I first asked this question on the Umbraco forums but haven't received a response yet, here is the link to the question: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/90878-editing-preview-window-sidebar-options

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no - it would not be possible without doing hacks in the Core that would be overwritten when you upgrade your site (unless you manually merge your changes in when updating).

If you however don't mind doing that - the file used for the preview function is  `/umbraco/preview/index.html`. You should look for the element with an `exitPreview()` click handler attached to it.

In later versions (7.10+) this modification will have to be done in `/umbraco/Views/Preview/Index.cshtml` instead, as these static files will be changed to MVC actions.

Comment: Thanks again Claus!

I had hoped that there was a quick fix that could be done without having to download and edit the Umbraco source code.

Comment: Actually you wouldn't really have to download the source code, as these are just view files existing in any built version of Umbraco. So modifying it in your site's /umbraco/ folder would be fine. You just need to keep in mind that when you update Umbraco - make sure not to overwrite this file. It is however still considered "hacking the Core" as you are modifying files that would be overwritten by standard upgrade procedure.

Comment: Okay I get you, that wouldn't be a problem in that case. There is no 'preview' folder under /umbraco/Views though. There is a umbpreview.html under umbraco/Views/content but it has very little HTML in it

Comment: As mentioned above - look in /umbraco/preview/index.html for the current version of Umbraco. It will be moved to the location you mention in version 7.10.0.